# Opencsv write list of string with ColumnPositionMapping

Tags: spring-boot, opencsv

I have code below

```
public class Carrier extends BaseDBClass{
@CsvBindByName
private String name;
@CsvRecurse
private CarrierType carrierType;
@CsvRecurse
private LocationAddress address;
@CsvBindAndSplitByName(elementType = String.class, writeDelimiter = ",")
private List<String> phoneNumbers;
}
```

---

```
List<Carrier> carriers = getAll();

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Carrier> mappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();

    mappingStrategy.setType(Carrier.class);
    String[] columns=new String[]{"id","name","description","carrierType", "country","city", "street", "streetNumber", "postalCode", "phoneNumbers", "createdAt", "modifiedAt"};
    mappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);

    response.getWriter().write(String.join(",", Arrays.stream(columns).map(column->"\""+column+"\"").toArray(String[]::new))+"\n");


    StatefulBeanToCsv<Carrier> beanWriter = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Carrier>(writer)
            .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
            .withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy)
            .build();
    beanWriter.write(carriers);
    response.getWriter().close();
```

The issue is that it writes only 1 phone number instead of list divided by comma. I`ve tried it without ColumnPositionMapping and it works but I want specify custom header names and custom column positions!